# Set up anonymous FTP for my new VPS?

Tags: vps, ftp

I am buying a VPS on Linode and have got most of my information correct on how to set things up unmanaged. One thing I wish to do on my server is serve files with FTP, such as through `ftp://mysite.com/pub/foo.txt` for a few reasons.

Do I need to install an FTP server, like vsftp and configure it to allow anonymous downloads? I am resourceful with these things but can not find the right first step in setting this up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which distribution (or even operating system) are you using? This answer assumes CentOS 5, but I'll try to edit it if you let me know the correct one.

Install vsftpd:
`yum install vsftpd`

Edit /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and ensure the following values are set (either change them or add them as necessary):
`local_enable=NO

anonymous_enable=YES

anon_upload_enable=NO

anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO

anon_root=/document/root/to/mysite.com/pub/foo.txt`

Restart vsftpd:
`/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart`

Test.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to understand to finish this, I am running Ubuntu 10.10 but am resourceful in package managers of each one so this will be fine. Thank you!